# Comparison of Object instances, C#

Tags: c#, comparison

I have two object instances and I would like to compare the values they hold. Since it is a large object difficult to compare by using watch list in C#, Visual Studio. Is there any free tools like BugAid. I don't want to keep writing both objects to a file and compare them as my first choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is reflection an option? It's not very efficient but if this is just for debugging then reflection can make something like this fairly trivial.

Here's an entire article about how it's possible: http://cyotek.com/blog/comparing-the-properties-of-two-objects-via-reflection

Comment: Interesting solution. Any suggestion for some tools we can attach with visual studio and do the comparison

Answer (score 6):

If this is for a permanent solution I would consider adding testing for equality into the custom objects themselves:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx